# Converting DateTime format

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parsing, datetime

I am trying to convert a string, `20151107` to the date format of `2015-11-07`.

Here's my code :

```
public static DateTime CustomDateFormat(this string resultdate)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(resultdate, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return dt;
}
```

However this returns something like this `11/07/2015 12:00:00 AM`.

Any idea?

Comment: You returning a `DateTime` which always has the time component. If you want that string value, you then need to convert the `DateTime` to a `string` - e.g. `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date returns like that because you are returning the entire `DateTime` object and since you are not providing a time it is default to `00:00:00.00`.

If you want to return the Date in a particular format, you can use the [Standard Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) or a [Custom Format String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).

In your case, you want `2015-11-07` which is a custom format of `yyyy-MM-dd` and can be used like so:

```
public static string CustomDateFormat(string resultdate)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(resultdate, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
}
```

Comment: Tried that already and it returned a "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime' " error.

Comment: Did you change the method signature?

Comment: @Qwerty make sure you change it to return a string, rather than a DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static String CustomDateFormat(this string resultdate)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(resultdate, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return dt.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd");
    }
```